# JavaScript confirmation before user leaves the page, not on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'd like the user to seen an alert only when leaving the page to confirm they want to. Currently, I think anything that is hitting `Page_Load` is showing the alert as well.

I have this code:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    return "Changes you made may not be saved.";
}
```

Expected: Only when x-ing out or clicking back show confirmation alert.

Actual: A `DropDownList` I have is causing alert to show as well as leaving the page.

EDIT:

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJob" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="combobox" 
    DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" OnClick="hideOnKeyPress(); return true;">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Are your DropDownList closing the browser tab in hideOnKeyPress() ?

Comment: `hideOnKeyPress()` is only hiding specific labels I have

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }
    return 'Sure?';
};
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still showing the alert when `DropDownList` gets selected

Comment: actually i tested it , this code used when you closed the browser tab. can i see your dropdownlist code

Comment: please remove your autopostback in your dropdownlist  and retry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
      // Cancel the event
      e.preventDefault();
      // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
      e.returnValue = 'Changes you made may not be saved.';
    });
```

Comment: Getting the same results back, might be something to do with my dropdown?

Comment: yeah, check your dropdown. Somewhere it's registered to trigger onbeforeunload event.